# Make custom URL clickable in Adobe PDF document

Tags: html, pdf, mirth

I'm in the process of creating a custom pdf document that will be uploaded in an application. There is a url link that needs to be made click but doesn't use the normal procotols such as http or https. I tried using a href in HMTL but since the url starts with *medstrat://the rest of the url info* when I open pdf it is not clickable. How can you make custom url's clickable in pdf?

I'm using a third party Application call Mirth that is creating the pdf using HTML code and exporting them to a folder share.

Comment: Are you using (or do you have access to) Adobe Acrobat? Are you converting HTML to PDF? Is so, which tool are you using? If you aren't using a tool, what is the original source data for your PDF and in which environment do you work? Do you need a PDF library or are you trying to create the PDF manually using a Desktop tool? You have to provide more info if you want an answer.

Comment: Updated my question, I'm using a third party application call Mirth that is using HTML code and converting it to a pdf.

Comment: I've added mirth as a tag. It doesn't look like a very active community though...

Comment: Can you show us the code you are using in mirth to generate those PDF?

Comment: "medstrat" in your case defines a protocol. In general the syntax is like this <a href="medstrat:18008675309">, where 18008675309 is just a fake data, so I'm not sure why you try to use it as a normal HTTP protocol i.e.: <a href="medstrat://18008675309">

Comment: If PDF is created by mirth than u no need to write anchor tag for URL. Just use URL as text and it will allow to click in PDF.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I created a hyperlink using A href so we could have the blue text as  a hyperlink. Even though this is a custom protocol the medstrat vendor requires there viewer and custom msi to be installed on server. The code that was used was <a href="medstrat://18008675309">Click PACS URL Link</a> and it ids working.